# Django Custom Auth Migration

Tags: python, django

I was trying to alter something on my user model in django and in the process I used makemigration to generate the migration file for it. But then decided against the whole thing, but now I have an unmigrated migration file located somewhere and I can't find it. I don't have an auth migrations folder in my app and I looked in the django auth migrations file and it's not there either. It shows up when I run python manage.py showmigrations as unmigrated, but I don't see the file anywhere. It doesn't show up when I do git status either.

Now I'm stuck because I can't run migrate without it trying to migrate it and erroring.  This is probably something silly that I'm overlooking. :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can either delete the table manually or inspect all migrations with:

```
./manage.py showmigrations my_app
```

Comment: Yeah. I know I can inspect the migrations, but how do I remove the unmigrated migration from the list? I don't see it in the table.